# "inferred type is FragmentManager? but FragmentManager was expected" error after moving to androidX

Tags: kotlin, androidx, fragmentmanager

I just moved my project to androidX. I used android studio refactor->upgrade to androidX. TargetSDK was already 28 and was working fine. So was not expecting many errors. But I was wrong and getting many errors, most of them are about fragmentManager

```
inferred type is FragmentManager? but FragmentManager was expected
```

This is when I am calling show method of a custom bottomSheetDialogue in a fragment.

```
bottomDialog.newInstance(//options here
                  ).show(fragmentManager, bottomDialog.TAG)
```

Comment: Can you show your import statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using parentFrgamentManager and it solved the issue. I tried with supportFragmentManager but it wasn't recognised, so used parentFragmentManager. This is the code I used.

```
bottomDialog.newInstance(//options here
                  ).show(parentFragmentManager, bottomDialog.TAG)
```

Answer (score 2):

The method is annotated as Nullable. Change like this

```
fragmentManager?.let { manager ->
    bottomDialog.newInstance(//options here
              ).show(manager, bottomDialog.TAG)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager` instead of a `android.app.FragmentManager`